# Зависает запрос

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, .net

Вот так я пытаюсь загрузить данные:

```
var cmd = new OleDbCommand($"select count(*) from {tableName}", connection);
RowsCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Но даже на такой вроде-бы простой запрос - все виснет намертво. Конкретно эта таблица довольно большая (около 60 мб), но ведь это `count` запрос! А вот с другими таблицами все работает без проблем (но они поменьше). Подскажите что делать?

upd. Подскажите хоть можно как-то продебажить внутренности OleDB? Может это поможет понять причину зависания.

Comment: Воспользоваться асинхронностью, т.е. использовать [ExecuteScalarAsync()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalarasync?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @Bulson причем тут вообще асинхронность? Если не работает синхронный вариант, то и асинхронный тоже не будет работать

Comment: А чем вам не нравиться асинхронный запрос? Он предотвратит зависание. Подумаешь данные появятся через пару минут (часов). Другой вариант - ограничить выборку 100 (1000) строк

Comment: @ArchDemon еще один... Я же русским языком написал что проблема не в длительности запроса. Запрос просто не проходит. Если тот же запрос запустить из тулзы по управлению этой субд то все отрабатывает за секунду.

Comment: "все виснет намертво" к вашему сведению - это блокировка потока отрисовки интерфейса вашим запросом. Что значит "Запрос просто не проходит"? У вас в программе стоит Гендальф, который кричит "Ты не пройдёшь!" ?

Comment: @ArchDemon приложение консольное, там нет интерфейса. Я просто дебажу и когда доходит до строки с вызовом `ExecuteScalar` то дальше не идет.

Comment: Он не "не идёт", а обрабатывает ваш запрос. Просто долго

Comment: @ArchDemon я в тысячный раз повторяю - не обрабатывает он нихрена. Хоть часами жди.

Comment: Подсчет строк - дело ресурсоемкое, так что терпения Вам. Ускорить можно так, запросить count по 1 колонке...типа select count (firstcolumn) from tablename